# How to add TTL to an existing table using the Oracle NoSQL Database Cloud Service Python SDK?

Tags: nosql, oracle-nosql

I already created a table and loaded a bunch of data into the table. Now, I want to implement the time-to-live feature in this table such that the records expire in 7 days.

Here's the create table command:

```
 CREATE TABLE userInfo (
     userID INTEGER,
     userName STRING,
     userAge INTEGER,
     userAddress JSON,
     PRIMARY KEY(userID))
```

How do I add time to live (TTL) without dropping, re-creating the table, and re-load the data using the Python SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Altering the `TTL` for a table only affects rows that are written after that time; it has no impact on existing rows.

It is not possible unless you rewrite every record with an explicit `TTL`.

If you are using release `21.1` you can use the `modification_time` function in a query to determine the last mod time. In `20.2` you can get the same information from a Row but you'll have to use the API to scan your table.

Do not forget, that you can also update the TTL for each row. But Multi-row update is not supported and you have also the API

```
UPDATE User $u SET TTL 3 hours WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE User $u SET TTL remaining_hours($p) + 3 hours WHERE id = 1;
```